# subprocess cmd is returning null (Python)

Tags: python

Trying to write a script that checks a directory for files which then uses the names of the files found to insert in to a subprocess command as shown below:

```
for filename in os.listdir('/home/dross/python/scripts/var/running/'):
    print(str(filename))
    cmd = 'app_query --username=dross --password=/home/dross/dross.txt "select row where label = \'Id: ' + filename + '\' SHOW status"'
    print(cmd)
    query = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    query.wait()
```

If I run the command manually from the command line there are 2 possible values returned "Error:No result" or "True"

When the "Error: No result" condition is true the script returns the same however when the "True" condition is present nothing is returned.
If the result of the print statement is copied and pasted in to the os command line it runs and returns "True"

What could be the deception I am seeing here ?
Is there a better approach to achieve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: Perhaps the `True` value is written to `stderr` instead?

Comment: Or possibly the other way around, it depends what the OP means by 'returned'.  There's no `.communicate()` call in the question, so it might be that `Error:No result` is being displayed on the screen and that the `True` would only show up if they do `query.communicate()`

Comment: @Martijn-Pieters`query = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: @dross can you confirm what you mean by 'returned' - do you mean printed to the screen? Are you using `query.communicate()` to get the output of `cmd`?

Comment: @Simon Fraser: Very new to python how could `query.communicate()` be written in to the existing code snippet? By "returned" I mean printed to the screen.

Comment: Bit too long for a comment, so I've added an answer.

Comment: iirc the first parameter for `Popen` needs to be a list, not a string. Try to pass there `cmd.split()`

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko that's true unless `shell=True` is also set. With that option a new subshell is started, which can interpret the string as a shell prompt would.

Comment: @dross: so where do you *read* the output produced by the command? I see no `query.communicate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a call to `.communicate()`, to read the results of the command through the pipe.

In your original `query = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` then anything send to `stderr` will be displayed on the screen, which seems to be what's happening for your error message. Anything sent to `stdout` will be sent to the pipe, ready for reading with `communicate()`

Some experimenting, showing that you won't see what's written to the `subprocess.PIPE` channels unless you communicate with the command you've run, and that `stderr` will display to the terminal if it's not redirected:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> query = subprocess.Popen('echo STDERR 1>&2', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
STDERR
>>> query.wait()
0
>>> print(query.communicate())
('', None)

>>> query = subprocess.Popen('echo STDERR 1>&2', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> query.wait()
0
>>> print(query.communicate())
('', 'STDERR\n')

>>> query = subprocess.Popen('echo STDOUT', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> query.wait()
0
>>> print(query.communicate())
('STDOUT\n', None)
```

So, to use your code from the question, you want something like this:

```
for filename in os.listdir('/home/dross/python/scripts/var/running/'):
    print(filename)  # print can convert to a string, no need for str()
    cmd = 'app_query --username=dross --password=/home/dross/dross.txt "select row where label = \'Id: ' + filename + '\' SHOW status"'
    print(cmd)
    query = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    query.wait()
    output, error = query.communicate()
    print("stdout: {}".format(output))
    print("stderr: {}".format(error))
```

Comment: This is interesting but it doesn't help me move forward from my problem.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood - from your description you were in the first situation, seeing the 'Error' line being printed out, and not calling `communicate()` to get the 'True' output.  What happens when you `print(query.communicate())` in your code?

Comment: **('True\n', '')** or **('None\n', '')** is returned with `print(query.communicate())`

Comment: So there's the 'True' you were missing before. You've told `Popen` to write 'standard output' to a PIPE for reading with `communicate()`, so that's where you'll find it. If you do the same for `stderr`, the second value will be the error message, if it's generated (That is, `communicate()` will return  `('', "Error:No result")`